# Making a Facebook Like Box draggable with JQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui

Hi I'm trying to make a Facebook Like Box draggable by placing it in a div. The Like Box shows up fine but doesn't drag. I have a twitter widget right before it that works just fine.

```
<div class="twitter"><script>new TWTR.Widget({version: 2, type: 'profile', rpp: 10, interval: 30000, width: 300, height: 300, theme: {shell: {background: '#7a7a7a', color: '#000000'}, tweets: {background: '#ffffff', color: '#000000', links: '#3586b8'}},features: {scrollbar: true, loop: false, live: true, behavior: 'all'}}).render().setUser('twitter').start();</script></div>


<div class="fb"><div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div></div>


$(function(){ $('.twitter').draggable({grid: [ 80, 80 ]}); $('.fb').draggable(); });
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You need to post the code you're using to generate the Facebook Like Box.  An example in jsFiddle would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to leave it out. I have tried calling the Like Box with all 3 options: HTML5, fbml and an iframe.

Comment: I'm new to it, but here's the jsFiddle I put together: http://jsfiddle.net/r3ueh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the `iframe` created by the Facebook like box is intercepting the `mousedown` event needed to make the draggable plugin work.

The div that you're creating around the like box is still draggable, just not over the `iframe` itself.  You can see that here - http://jsfiddle.net/3K9uX/1/.

I don't believe it will be possible to get this to work as you'd like.  There's a potential solution discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420327/jquery-draggable-handler-inside-iframe).

What I would do is create a heading above the like box that allows the user to drag the whole box.

**Live Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/3K9uX/2/

Comment: Thank you! This was incredibly helpful.