# Draggable iFrame registers click instead of drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I have an iFrame to a YouTube video with a container around it:

```
<div class="draggable resizable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Eeue7FWnNJs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

What I'nm trying to accomplish is to make this video draggable through jQuery UI, but still playable when it's not being dragged. After some research into the subject, I came on to the following:

```
iframeFix: true
```

as an option in the `.draggable` function, however, this didn't appear to do anything, and my problem remained.

After that I tried making a div appear on drag as an overlay of sorts:

```
.frameOverlay
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

This is the CSS I used for the overlay, then I placed a div with class `frameOverlay` randomly in my HTML and in Javascript I did this:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
  start: function(event, ui) {
     $('.frameOverlay').show();
   },
   stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(".frameOverlay").hide();
   }
})
```

However, this also didn't solve the problem. The iframe still registers what's supposed to be a drag as a click, making it play the video. Here's a fiddle with my problem: [Click me](https://jsfiddle.net/3rjy0efa/)

Does anyone have a working fix for this problem?

Thanks.

Edit: I'd like to avoid adding handles to the iframe, since it'll (slightly) inconvenience the user.

Comment: Have you tried adding a handle?

Comment: Your Fiddle was missing the jQuery library. Just FYI.

Comment: Ideally you would want to detect events before the iframe and decide whether they get passed through or not.  Might be possible but I haven't figured out a way because events usually bubble up from children and not other way around.  I have a partial solution, based off this idea, not sure that it is any less inconvenient then using a handle.  You can toggle whether to drag the iframe or have access to it's controls.  Either by clicking the button, or using the right arrow key when the iframe is not focused to switch between modes. https://jsfiddle.net/sfzjrw6x/1/

Comment: @Trevor Since your Fiddle helped me create the defenitive solution, would you post this as an answer, so I can reward you the bounty? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can enable/disable access to the iFrame, if disabled events such as drag will be available.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn-drag">Draggable</button>
<button class="active btn-play">I Frame Controls</button>
<br />
<br />
<div id="drag" class="draggable resizable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
    <iframe id="frame" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Eeue7FWnNJs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    iframeFix: true
});

$('.btn-drag, .btn-play').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('btn-drag')){
    $('.btn-drag').addClass('active');
    $('.btn-play').removeClass('active');
    $('#frame').css('pointer-events','none');
  }
  else{
    $('.btn-drag').removeClass('active');
    $('.btn-play').addClass('active');
    $('#frame').css('pointer-events','auto');
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {  
  if(!e.keyCode === 39){
    return false;
  }
  if($('#frame').css('pointer-events') === 'auto'){
    $('.btn-drag, .btn-play').toggleClass('active');
    $('#frame').css('pointer-events','none');
  }
  else{
    $('.btn-play, .btn-drag').toggleClass('active');
    $('#frame').css('pointer-events','auto');
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sfzjrw6x/1/)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following:

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3rjy0efa/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="frameOverlay"></div>
<div class="draggable resizable">
  <div class="handle"></div>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Eeue7FWnNJs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.handle {
  width: 558px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 23px;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}

.frameOverlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
  handle: ".handle",
  iframeFix: true,
  start: function(event, ui) {
    $('.frameOverlay').show();
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(".frameOverlay").hide();
  }
});
```

This gives you something to grab onto that is not inside the iFrame.